# Salesforce APEX REST API : Unable to provide json payload to @httppost function

Tags: rest, salesforce, http-post, apex

I developed an APEX class to create a RestResource, and especially a way to deal with a HTTP POST request (API REST).
This function creates an event platform.
It takes a JSON payload and parse it (manually since there is some protected keywords such as 'number'

When I execute a curl command to test it, it fails (if the payload is empty, it succeeds to start and run the function, but when the payload contains the fields, I got an error seemingly not catch by try/catch structure)

Can you help ?

Here is the curl command (after getting a token) :

```
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer xxxxxxxx" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
  "message_id": "12345",
  "mobileNumber": "1234567890",
  "text": "This is a test message",
  "sim_card_number": "SIM123",
  "reception_date": "2023-10-18 14:30:00"
}' "https://myinstanceoftest.sandbox.my.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/incomingTextMessages"
```

and get this error :

```
{"message":"Unexpected parameter encountered during deserialization: message_id at [line:1, column:17]","errorCode":"JSON_PARSER_ERROR"}]'
```

and the APEX class :

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/incomingTextMessages/*')
global with sharing class AC14_IncomingTextMessage {

    // Define the JSON structure to match the incoming data.
    global class IncomingTextMessage {
        public String message_id;
        public String mobileNumber;
        public String text;
        public String sim_card_number;
        public String reception_date;
    }

    // Define the response structure.
    global class Response {
        public String status;
        public String message;
    }

    @HttpPost
    global static Response createIncomingTextMessage(String jsonPayload) {
        System.debug('Received JSON Message: ' + jsonPayload);
        
        Response response = new Response();
        
        try {

            Map<String, Object> jsonMap = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(jsonPayload);
            
            // Create an instance of the IncomingTextMessage class and manually map the field "number" to "mobileNumber."
            IncomingTextMessage incomingMessage = new IncomingTextMessage();
            incomingMessage.message_id = (String) jsonMap.get('message_id');
            incomingMessage.mobileNumber = (String) jsonMap.get('number');
            incomingMessage.text = (String) jsonMap.get('text');
            incomingMessage.sim_card_number = (String) jsonMap.get('sim_card_number');
            incomingMessage.reception_date = (String) jsonMap.get('reception_date');

            // Create a new Platform Event and set its fields.
            IncomingTextMessage__e newEvent = new IncomingTextMessage__e(
                Message_Id__c = incomingMessage.message_id,
                mobileNumber__c = incomingMessage.mobileNumber,
                Text__c = incomingMessage.text,
                Sim_Card_Number__c = incomingMessage.sim_card_number,
                Reception_Date__c = DateTime.valueOf(incomingMessage.reception_date)
            );

            // Publish the Platform Event.
            EventBus.publish(newEvent);

            response.status = 'Success';
            response.message = 'Platform Event created successfully';
        } catch (Exception e) {
            response.status = 'Error';
            response.message = 'Error processing the request: ' + e.getMessage();
        }
                
        return response;
    }
}
```

I tried several curl test showing that empty payload works fine (I mean, it fails bu as excepted and catch by try/catch structure)
I also developed test class that is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I remember for POST you either:

1. don't bother passing any parameters to the method
2. tweak the JSON a bit

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_restrequest.htm

> If the Apex method has no parameters, then Apex REST copies the HTTP
> request body into the RestRequest.requestBody property. If there are
> parameters, then Apex REST attempts to deserialize the data into those
> parameters and the data won't be deserialized into the
> RestRequest.requestBody property.

For 1 the idea is that you can read everything you need from

```
RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
System.debug(req.requestURI);
System.debug(req.requestBody);
```

Which well... Sucks a bit if you hope to reuse this code in another non-API context.

For 2 I think you need to pass a JSON where top-level element(s) match your method's attribute name(s). So check if cURL works with something like

```
{
"jsonPayload": "{\r\n  \"message_id\": \"12345\",\r\n  \"mobileNumber\": \"1234567890\",\r\n  \"text\": \"This is a test message\",\r\n  \"sim_card_number\": \"SIM123\",\r\n  \"reception_date\": \"2023-10-18 14:30:00\"\r\n}"
}
```

This one is clunky as well, you have JSON-ception.

Normally I'd create a helper wrapper class to store the fields and pass an object of that class: `myMethod(Wrapper w)`. And JSON like

```
{
    "w" : {
        "message_id" : "12345",
        "mobileNumber": "123"
    }
}
```

Sounds like you can't do that because you have no control over the incoming data and it contains reserved keywords?

Well, go with option1 and if you ever need to reuse this code - create a helper method that does accept parameters. Mark the `createIncomingTextMessage()` as POST and have it call the "normal" one `createIncomingTextMessage(String payload)` or `createIncomingTextMessage(Wrapper w)`?

Comment: Great ! Solution 1 was straightforward

Answer (score -1):

You can also enhance your practical experience with Salesforce by checking out saasguru Salesforce Labs. It's a fantastic resource tailored to help you bridge the gap between theoretical knowledge and real-world application. What's noteworthy is that saasguru Salesforce Labs is accessible for free, which makes it an accessible option for anyone looking to enhance their skills.

Feel free to explore it at your own pace and see how it complements your learning journey. Here' the link - https://www.saasguru.co/salesforce-labs-real-time-projects-for-practice/